# Vertical alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I've been able to vertically align some text with `\vspace*{\fill}` but below the aligned line is some more text and a figure which causes the aligned line to be above the middle of the page. How can I make sure it's at the center (horizontally and vertically aligned) while keeping the text below it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\parbox{5cm}{\centering \textsc{Metafysica \\ \& \\Natuurfilosofie}}} \\
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[trim={0, 0.65cm, 0, 0},clip,width=0.30\linewidth]{logozw}
\end{figure}
\vspace{-3ex}
Universiteit Gent \\
Faculteit Letteren en Wijsbegeerte \\
Vakgroep Wijsbegeerte en Moraalwetenschap \\
Notities bij de lessen van professor V. D.
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can build a zero height box with the standard LaTeX commands; you want a box that sits on the baseline with respect to the last line in it and has zero height:

```
\parbox[b][0pt]{\textwidth}{...}
```

does what you want.

I'd avoid `\resizebox` for the title: you better control the size with explicit font size changing commands.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry} % just to show the page frame

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\topskip0pt

\vspace*{\fill}

\centering

{\LARGE
  \textsc{Metafysica}\par
  \&\par
  \textsc{Natuurfilosofie}\par
}

\vspace*{\fill}

\parbox[b][0pt]{\textwidth}{
  \centering
  \includegraphics[trim={0, 0.65cm, 0, 0},clip,width=0.30\linewidth]{logozw}

  %\vspace{-3ex} % possibly useful, depending on the picture

  Universiteit Gent \\
  Faculteit Letteren en Wijsbegeerte \\
  Vakgroep Wijsbegeerte en Moraalwetenschap \\
  Notities bij de lessen van professor V. D.\par
  \vspace{-\prevdepth} % the descenders go under the baseline
}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why avoid the resizebox? What is a good way to increase the font size above \Huge? (Perhaps I'd better ask that last question somewhere else.)

Comment: @Johannes You can also say `\fontsize{24}{32}\selectfont` or similar (the first argument is the font size, the second is the baselineskip). Assuming your font is freely scalable, it's more flexible and predictable.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different take on what you might be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering\strut

  \vfill

  \scalebox{3}{\begin{tabular}{c}
    \textsc{Metafysica} \\ \& \\ \textsc{Natuurfilosofie}
  \end{tabular}}

  \vfill

  \noindent\strut\smash{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\linewidth}@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    Universiteit Gent \\
    Faculteit Letteren en Wijsbegeerte \\
    Vakgroep Wijsbegeerte en Moraalwetenschap \\
    Notities bij de lessen van professor V.~D.
  \end{tabular}}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

The main approach is to `\smash` the contents of the lower portion of your `titlepage`. That way it takes up no vertical space on the page. For centering content, I've used a `\linewidth`-spanning `tabular`. You could also consider using the [`tikzpagenodes` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) to identify specific locations on the page for placement.

The frames added to the output is as a result of the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe).